# Group by several weeks in a row

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have table like.

| deviation_id | week_number |
| --- | --- |
| 262 | 5 |
| 262 | 6 |
| 262 | 7 |
| 262 | 13 |
| 264 | 8 |
| 264 | 9 |
| 264 | 11 |
| 264 | 12 |
| 264 | 13 |

I need select deviation_id by several weeks in a row like:

| deviation_id | begin_week_num | end_week_num |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 262 | 5 | 7 |
| 264 | 8 | 9 |
| 264 | 11 | 13 |

How can i do this in PostgreSQL?

Comment: use a case expression in your group by. `case when week_number between 5 and 7 then 1 when week_number between 8 and 9 then 2 when week_number between 11 and 13 then 3 end`  If that's what you mean, mock up an expected result to clarify using your sample data.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thahk you for feed back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for feed back. I think i found a decision on my question.

```
select tt."repeat", tt.deviation_id, min(tt.week_number), max(tt.week_number)
from (
select tt.*
from (
    select tt.*, count(tt."repeat")over(partition by tt."repeat") as "count"
    from (
        select tt.deviation_id, tt.week_number, --сount(tt.deviation_id)
            row_number() over(partition by tt.deviation_id order by tt.week_number)-tt.week_number as "repeat"
        from public.tasks_task tt 
        where tt."year" =2022 and tt.orgunit_id =3000 and tt.deviation_id in ('262','264'))tt)tt
where tt."count">1) tt
group by 1,2
order by 2,3
```

Answer (score 0):

As week number is an integer

```
GROUP BY week_number / 3
```

would group 3 weeks together.

```
1, 2 or 3 / 3 = 0
4, 5 or 6 / 3 = 1
7, 8 or 9 / 3 = 2
...
```

If your groups are irregular you will have to use a case statement as xQbert suggests, but you will have to code for all possible groups up to week_number = 53.